# Typescript rename type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

how can I get vscode to suggest the key of mainMap, as socketId: string instead of only string?

```
type SocketId = string;
type User = {displayName: string}
let mainMap = new Map<SocketId, User>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an intersection with `{}`. This will not have any impact on assignability, but it will prevent TS form inlining the alias:

```
type SocketId = string & {};
type User = {displayName: string}
let mainMap = new Map<SocketId, User>();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gYwNYWASQCZQLxQM7ABOAlgHYDmUAZFAN4C+A3AFCiRQCqeEhOdGxPGAA2AQxAA5UQFsIALnxEy5es2Goo00WQCyosH1IQA7lD1gAPPGSpMAGk7dCAPgAUASkZA)

You might also consider branded types to check that the socket id is valid.

Comment: Thank you so very much

Comment: It's the common usage for simulating Nominal Type.

Comment: @Zheeeng just to be clear, in the example above `SockId` is is still just a string and will be compatible with string, you'd have to add a brand to it to make it nominal.